# How to get the url redirection status using urllib2.urlopen()?

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2, urlopen

Im using urllib2.urlOpen(request) to send a Http packet. The response.getcode() show 200 even during a successful redirection.

I want to know if there is a redirection and what is redriection the status (301 or 302).

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I dont care about the final url ... BUT the STATUS either 301 or 302.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 r = requests.get(url)
 print r.status_code
```

Comment: Then I don't know. Try the answer below

Comment: Got the answer using request.get too 

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", verify=False, allow_redirects=False, timeout=5)
print r.status_code

would give the status even if there is a redirect...

Answer (score 0):

Write your own [urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects) which will get called in case of a redirect:

```
class CustomHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        # handle redirect here
        pass

    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302
```

Then register it using `install_opener`:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(CustomHTTPRedirectHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://yoururl/")
```

Comment: is there any way to use the same without creating a class?

Comment: Apart from "cheating" and checking whether the response url is not the same as the request url, there is no other way that I'm aware of.